# The Android emulator process has unexpectedly stopped running. The instance <device_name> is now stopped

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, device

I installed the following environment to start developping android applications.

OS: windows 7 64

Java: jdk 1.8.0_77

Eclipse:  eclipse-android-neon-2-incubation-win32-x86_64

SDK:  android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows    (Android 6.0  7.0 e 7.1.1)

All was ok until the moment to start AVD.

I created various ADV configurations but when starting I received always the same error (it changes only the device_name):

**The Android emulator process has unexpectedly stopped running. The instance (device_name) is now stopped.**

This is one of ADV configuration tried

[image]

This is the error throwd after starting

[image]

Have you any suggestion to me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue ...

There is no log cat or any other error shown in eclipse neon 2.

Up:

you have to select the project instead of the class.

i do not get anymore this error.