# The Android emulator process has unexpectedly stopped running. The instance (device_name) is now stopped in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I installed the following environment to start developing android applications.

```
OS: windows 10 64

Java: jdk 1.8.0_77

Eclipse: eclipse-android-neon

sdk:installer_r24.4.1-windows
```

when I try to run the project always, i am getting the same error as
**The Android emulator process has unexpectedly stopped running. The instance (device_name) is now stopped.**

I tried all the ways by uninstalling sdk tools and installing again but not worked and I know my question is duplicate one but no answer worked for me.

This is the error thrown after running the project.

[image]

AVD settings

[image]

Please give me any suggestion.

Comment: Might be, you do not have suficiente RAM in your system

Comment: My system RAM size is 4GB

Comment: https://www.quora.com/is-8-GB-RAM-enough-for-Android-OS-Development     I think RAM is the issue.

Comment: except eclipse close all your application which are ruuning in your system

Comment: I used android studio at that time emulator worked fine,but in eclipse iam getting this error.

Comment: I closed all other applications, but same error@parvezalamkhan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759715/the-android-emulator-process-has-unexpectedly-stopped-running-the-instance-dev

Comment: check your setting

Comment: which settings?

Comment: Android virtual device (AVD) setting

Comment: AVD settings     https://i.stack.imgur.com/A17il.png